# Can shaitan control our mind

Tags: practical-islam, shaitan

Quetion about shaitan in islam.can shaitan control our mind  filling in negative thoughts

Answer (score 2):

As for as the power of Satan, no creature, no matter how powerful, can act without Allah’s (JJ) sanction. For this reason, Satan has power to misguide only those people who have relinquished their belief in one Allah (JJ) and have surrendered to the temptations of Satan. Accordingly, Satan himself admits that he has no power over Allah’s (JJ) sincere servants when he swears, in the holy Quran, Surat al-Hijr (15), Verse 39-40:

```
       “I shall misguide them all except Your sincere servants.”
```

Satan’s sole influence over man is by way of whispering temptations. He can never strip man of his free will. In philosophical terms, Satan’s non-materiality is not complete, therefore he cannot reach the lofty station that the spirit of the righteous enjoys. Giving into the temptation of the carnal soul (al-nafs al-’ammarah) opens the way for satanic influence thereby pulling man into Satan’s traps. The sole respite from his grasp is to turn one’s attention to Allah (JJ) and seek his protection. Allah (JJ) says in Quran,

```
         “You (Satan) have no power over my servants.”
```

This site has detailed discussion on the same topic...
[Detailed elaboration is listed here....](https://www.al-islam.org/faith-and-reason-ayatullah-mahdi-hadavi-tehrani/question-18-power-satan-and-jinn#fref_83fbb925_2)

Answer (score -1):

Narrated `Aisha:

> that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was affected by magic, so much that he used
> to think that he had done something which in fact, he did not do, and
> he invoked his Lord (for a remedy). Then (one day) he said, "O
> `Aisha!) Do you know that Allah has advised me as to the problem I consulted Him about?"` Aisha said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! What's
> that?" He said, "Two men came to me and one of them sat at my head and
> the other at my feet, and one of them asked his companion, 'What is
> wrong with this man?' The latter replied, 'He is under the effect of
> magic.' The former asked, 'Who has worked magic on him?' The latter
> replied, 'Labid bin Al-A'sam.' The former asked, 'With what did he
> work the magic?' The latter replied, 'With a comb and the hair, which
> are stuck to the comb, and the skin of pollen of a date-palm tree.'
> The former asked, 'Where is that?' The latter replied, 'It is in
> Dharwan.' Dharwan was a well in the dwelling place of the (tribe of)
> Bani Zuraiq. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) went to that well and returned to
> `Aisha, saying, 'By Allah, the water (of the well) was as red as the infusion of Hinna, (1) and the date-palm trees look like the heads of devils.'` Aisha added, Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) came to me and informed
> me about the well. I asked the Prophet, 'O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), why
> didn't you take out the skin of pollen?' He said, 'As for me, Allah
> has cured me and I hated to draw the attention of the people to such
> evil (which they might learn and harm others with).' " Narrated
> Hisham's father: `Aisha said, "Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was bewitched, so
> he invoked Allah repeatedly requesting Him to cure him from that
> magic)." Hisham then narrated the above narration.

(See Hadith No. 658, Vol. 7)

> حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ مُنْذِرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَنَسُ بْنُ عِيَاضٍ،
> عَنْ هِشَامٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ ـ رضى الله عنها أَنَّ
> رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم طُبَّ حَتَّى إِنَّهُ لَيُخَيَّلُ
> إِلَيْهِ قَدْ صَنَعَ الشَّىْءَ وَمَا صَنَعَهُ، وَإِنَّهُ دَعَا رَبَّهُ
> ثُمَّ قَالَ ‏"‏ أَشَعَرْتِ أَنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ أَفْتَانِي فِيمَا
> اسْتَفْتَيْتُهُ فِيهِ ‏"‏‏.‏ فَقَالَتْ عَائِشَةُ فَمَا ذَاكَ يَا
> رَسُولَ اللَّهِ قَالَ ‏"‏ جَاءَنِي رَجُلاَنِ فَجَلَسَ أَحَدُهُمَا
> عِنْدَ رَأْسِي، وَالآخَرُ عِنْدَ رِجْلَىَّ فَقَالَ أَحَدُهُمَا
> لِصَاحِبِهِ مَا وَجَعُ الرَّجُلِ قَالَ مَطْبُوبٌ‏.‏ قَالَ مَنْ طَبَّهُ
> قَالَ لَبِيدُ بْنُ الأَعْصَمِ‏.‏ قَالَ فِيمَا ذَا قَالَ فِي مُشْطٍ
> وَمُشَاطَةٍ وَجُفِّ طَلْعَةٍ‏.‏ قَالَ فَأَيْنَ هُوَ قَالَ فِي
> ذَرْوَانَ، وَذَرْوَانُ بِئْرٌ فِي بَنِي زُرَيْقٍ ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَتْ
> فَأَتَاهَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ثُمَّ رَجَعَ إِلَى
> عَائِشَةَ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ وَاللَّهِ لَكَأَنَّ مَاءَهَا نُقَاعَةُ
> الْحِنَّاءِ، وَلَكَأَنَّ نَخْلَهَا رُءُوسُ الشَّيَاطِينِ ‏"‏‏.‏
> قَالَتْ فَأَتَى رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَأَخْبَرَهَا عَنِ
> الْبِئْرِ، فَقُلْتُ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ فَهَلاَّ أَخْرَجْتَهُ قَالَ
> ‏"‏ أَمَّا أَنَا فَقَدْ شَفَانِي اللَّهُ، وَكَرِهْتُ أَنْ أُثِيرَ
> عَلَى النَّاسِ شَرًّا ‏"‏‏.‏ زَادَ عِيسَى بْنُ يُونُسَ وَاللَّيْثُ
> عَنْ هِشَامٍ عَنْ أَبِيهِ عَنْ عَائِشَةَ قَالَتْ سُحِرَ النَّبِيُّ صلى
> الله عليه وسلم فَدَعَا وَدَعَا وَسَاقَ الْحَدِيثَ

Reference    : Sahih al-Bukhari 6391
In-book reference    : Book 80, Hadith 86
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 8, Book 75, Hadith 400

Comment: It is good to cite but it would be appreciated if you could formulate the answer to the question you draw thereof.